# Why is $[\top,\bot]$ the character of the coproduct inclusion $i_1$?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, topos-theory, pullback

$\require{AMScd}$In an elementary topos $\mathbf{C}$, why should $m=[\top,\bot]$ be the character morphism of the first coproduct inclusion $i_0:\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{1}$?

I have tried to show that if we take $k:P\to\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{1}$ as the pullback of $\top$ and $m$
$$ \begin{CD} P @>k>> \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{1} \\ @V!_PVV @VVmV \\ \mathbf{1} @>>\top> \Omega\end{CD}$$
then $P$ is a terminal object and thus $P\cong\mathbf{1}$ so that
$$ \begin{CD} \mathbf{1} @>i_0>> \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{1} \\ @V=VV @VVmV \\ \mathbf{1} @>>\top> \Omega\end{CD}$$
is also a pullback.

This is motivated by my previous question [Proof that $[\top,\bot]$ is monic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129093/proof-that-top-bot-is-monic?noredirect=1#comment8543634_4129093) and the first answer that was given.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of using the universal property of the pullback to show that $P$ in your diagram must be $1$ is a good one!

To show that there's a (unique) arrow from my favorite object $X$ into $P$, we have to show that there's a (unique) pair of arrows from $X \to 1$ and $X \to 1+1$ making the diagram commute.

Of course, we're halfway there out of the gate, since we know there's a unique arrow $X \to 1$. For the other arrow, since $m = [\top, \bot]$ it's easy to see that the arrow $i_0 \ \circ \ ! : X \to 1+1$ makes the diagram commute.  This also gives us $k = i_0$ when we set $X = P = 1$.

As an only-slightly-tricky exercise, can you show that $i_0 \ \circ \ !$ was the only choice of $X \to 1+1$ making the diagram commute, so we really do get uniqueness?

---

**Edit:**

We know that toposes are [extensive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category), so if $f : X \to 1+1$ we know that $X$ is actually isomorphic to $X_0 + X_1$ where $f \restriction X_j = i_j \ \circ \ !$.

Then if $f$ makes the diagram commute, we know that

$$X_j \hookrightarrow X \overset{f}{\to} 1+1 \overset{[\top,\bot]}{\longrightarrow} \Omega = \top$$

for both $X_j$. Of course, since $\top \neq \bot$, this means $X_1 \cong 0$, $X \cong X_0$, and $f = i_0 \ \circ \ !$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Well, the slightly tricky exercise is where I have been stuck for hours. Also I couldn't prove that $k=i_0 !_P$, which would solve all of my problems, so can you expand your answer please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually boarding a plane right now, but I'll expand on my answer when I land. Now that I think about it slightly harder, I'm starting to worry the exercise was less-than-only-slightly-tricky after all... See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328468/how-many-morphisms-from-1-to-11-can-there-be), for instance...

Comment: The fact that toposes are extensive is, I think, a consequence of the Fundamental theorem (i.e $\mathbb{C}/a$ is a topos) and I was trying to avoid using it in any form. It seems that any proof that $[\top,\bot]$ is monic uses the Fundamental theorem somehow, so your answer is the best I can hope for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. Sorry I don't have a more elementary answer. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me will show up and know what to do!